# Unknown 3x3 matrix, how to identify its identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

An unknown 3x3 matrix A can be identified with the ero1, ero2, ero3, ero4. By following the order of operations below, it can be transformed into an identitymatrix:

$
ero_1: \mathbf{r}_1 +  \mathbf{r}_2 \rightarrow \mathbf{r}_2 \\
ero_2: -\frac{1}{5}\mathbf{r}_3 \rightarrow \mathbf{r}_3 \\
ero_3: \mathbf{r}_1 \leftrightarrow \mathbf{r}_3 \\ 
ero_4: 10\mathbf{r}_3 + \mathbf{r}_1 \rightarrow \mathbf{r}_1  
$

Why is one of the matrixproducts  $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{E}_4\mathbf{E}_3\mathbf{E}_2\mathbf{E}_1, \mathbf{A}\mathbf{E}_1\mathbf{E}_2\mathbf{E}_3\mathbf{E}_4, \mathbf{E}_1\mathbf{E}_2\mathbf{E}_3\mathbf{E}_4\mathbf{A}   $, $\mathbf{E}_4\mathbf{E}_3\mathbf{E}_2\mathbf{E}_1\mathbf{A} $ the identity matrix?

I'm unsure how to identify it as I don't know A. I believe the question is related to the fact that $AB \neq BA$ when it comes to matrices but I can't calculate it.

Comment: kindly include your thoughts in the post

Comment: Sorry, i've added it now.

Comment: Suppose the case $A=\begin{pmatrix}3 &0 \\ 0 &3 \end{pmatrix}$ with  $ero_1=R_1\to\frac13R_1$ and $ero_2=R_2\to\frac13R_2$  . Then what matrix product gives the identity matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guide:

- After you perform the first row operation, the matrix becomes $E_1A$.
- Write down what happens after the second, third and fourth.